# Given are $3$ propositional formulas. Do we have that $\Phi \vDash \varphi _3$?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Given are these $3$ propositional formulas:
>
> $\varphi_1 := (A_1 \wedge 0)$
>
> $\varphi_2 := (\neg (A_0 \rightarrow \neg A_1) \rightarrow A_1)$
>
> $\varphi_3 := ((A_o \vee A_1) \rightarrow (A_o \wedge A_1))$
>
> and $\Phi := \left\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2\right\}$
>
> Do we have that $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$ ?

I think what I need to do is create truth table for each formula and then check if all models of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are included in $\varphi_3$?

Table for $\varphi_1$:

```
A1   0   (A1∧0)
 0   0      0
 1   0      0
```

Table for $\varphi_2$:

```
A0   A1   ¬(A0 → ¬A1)   ¬(A0 → ¬A1) → A1
 0    0         0               1
 0    1         0               1
 1    0         0               1
 1    1         1               1
```

Table for $\varphi_3$:

```
A0   A1   A0∨A1   A0∧A1   (A0∨A1)→(A0∧A1)
 0    0     0       0            1
 0    1     1       0            0
 1    0     1       0            0
 1    1     1       1            1
```

So now we need to check if every model of $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ is also a model in $\varphi_3$ ? Then $\varphi_2$ is already fine because every combination is true there. $\varphi_1$ is fine too because for $A_1=0$ we have a model in $\varphi_3$ and for $A_1=1$ we have a model as well.

Is it correct like that?

Comment: What model satisfies $A_1\wedge 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, however your conclusion is a bit off.

$\Phi \models \varphi_3 \iff \forall M:M\models \Phi \implies M \models \varphi_3$ with $M\models \Phi \iff (M\models \varphi_1  \land M\models \varphi_1$)

So you basically need to show that every model for $\Phi$ is a model for $\varphi_3$ as well.

Notice that $\varphi_1$ has no models at all, as it always results in false. Therefore $\Phi$ has no model as well. Hence $\Phi \models P$ for every propositional formula $P$. Even  $\Phi \models \bot$.

Comment: So this means that we don't have $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$ because not all models in $\varphi_2$ are in $\varphi_3$, namely the second and third row of truth table $\varphi_2$?

Comment: We DO have $\Phi \models \varphi_3$, because "all" models, that evaluate $\varphi_1$ AND $\varphi_2$ to true (there are no such models), also evaluate $\varphi_3$ to true. You're right that not all models of $\varphi_2$ are models $\varphi_3$, which means $\varphi_2 \not\models \varphi_3$. This does not say anything about $\Phi$ tho. In terms of truth tables, you need to search for the assignments of your variables $A_1$ and $A_2$ that satisfy $\varphi_1$ AND $\varphi_2$ and make sure that those assignments also satisfy $\varphi_3$. If that's the case then $\Phi \models \varphi_3$

Answer (score 1):

$\{\varphi_1, \varphi_2\}\models \varphi_3$ means that in all interpretations* in which statements $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are mutually true, then $\varphi_3$ will also be true.

(* that is, basically, the truth assignments for $A_0$ and $A_1$)

So, which interpretation are *both* statements true?   What does *that* mean?

Comment: In $\varphi_1$ we don't have any model but in $\varphi_2$, every row of the truth table is a model. Now in order we have $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$, all the models of $\varphi_2$ must be a model for $\varphi_3$ as well? This isn't the case because second and third row in $\varphi_3$ are false. Thus we don't have that $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$. Is it correct like that?

Comment: Hint: Vacuous Truths. @cnmesr  Are there any models that make $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ both true but that make $\varphi_3$ false?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$ if and only if the following statement is true:

For all valuations $v$ (a valuation $v$ is an assignment of truth-values to the atomic statements involved ... basically a valuation corresponds to a row in the truth-table):

$$\text{If $v$ sets all statements in $\Phi$ to true, then $v$ sets $\varphi_3$ to true}$$

Well, as you saw, there actually isn't any valuation that sets all statements in $\Phi$ to true (in fact, no valuation will set $\varphi_1$ by itself to true)

Put differently, for any valuation $v$, the statement that $v$ sets all statements in $\Phi$ to true is False. Hence, the 'if' part of the above statement is False, but that means that the whole statement is true. In other words, it *is* true that for all valuations $v$:

$$\text{If $v$ sets all statements in $\Phi$ to true, then $v$ sets $\varphi_3$ to true}$$

And therefore $\Phi \vDash \varphi_3$